# Zend Framework Hostname validator

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need an URL validator inside a form. Now I'm using:

```
$url = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('url');
$url->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Hostname());
```

The code above will validate URL's like: `www.domain.com` but will fail validation for `http://www.domain.com`.

What validator should I use in order to validate both, with and without protocol URL's.

Comment: You need to validate both? or just domain name is important?

Comment: I need that both URL's will pass the validation process.

Answer (score 1):

This will validate both domain and uri:

```
$form->addElement ('text', 'url',array(
            'validators' => array (
                    array(
                        'Callback', 
                        true, 
                        ['callback' => function($value) {
                            if (Zend_Uri::check($value)) {
                                $hostnameValidator = new Zend_Validate_Hostname(Zend_Validate_Hostname::ALLOW_DNS); //do not allow local hostnames, this is the default
                                $uriHttp = Zend_Uri_Http::fromString($value);
                                return $hostnameValidator->isValid($uriHttp->getHost());
                            }
                            return false;
                        }], 
                        'messages' => [Zend_Validate_Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Please enter a valid URL']
                    )
                )
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it with Zend_Validate_Hostname. The way you could do it, is to write your own validator that will split sting into 2 parts - and validate them using Zend_Validate_Hostname for hostname and Zend_Validate_InArray for protocol

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the scheme http, or implement a new re-usable validator
http://www.rondobley.com/2011/09/24/how-to-validate-a-url-with-a-scheme-and-hostname-in-zend-framework/